# Use type parameters with exact type instead of extending

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function that accepts a parameter that can have one of two different types. I want to type the return type based on that parameter.

I need to use a type parameter so I can reference the parameter type in the return type. But I don't want to use the `extends` keyword as that would allow putting any supertype into the function. Example:

```js
type Cat = {
  name: string;
}

type CatWithOwner = {
  owner: string;
} & Cat;

const getNicknamedCat = <C extends Cat | CatWithOwner>(
  cat: C
): C extends CatWithOwner
  ? CatWithOwner & { nickname: string }
  : Cat & { nickname: string } => {
  return { ...cat, nickname: name + "y" };
};


// works
getNicknamedCat({ name: "Nick" })

// works, return type also has the owner
getNicknamedCat({ name: "Nick", owner: "Winston" })

// works, too, but I don't want this. I want to forbid non-Cat/CatWithOwner-keys
getNicknamedCat({ name: "Nick", unrelated: "foo" })
```

I need the type parameter so I can reference it in the return type but is there any way to "assign" the type parameter a type instead of extending?

What I want is something like this:

```js
const getNicknamedCat = <C is Cat | CatWithOwner>(
  cat: C
): C extends CatWithOwner
  ? CatWithOwner & { nickname: string }
  : Cat & { nickname: string } => {
  return { ...cat, nickname: name + "y" };
};


// works
getNicknamedCat({ name: "Nick" })

// works, return type also has the owner
getNicknamedCat({ name: "Nick", owner: "Winston" })

// error, "unrelated" is not expected
getNicknamedCat({ name: "Nick", unrelated: "foo" })
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wg8yvN) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yeah, that seems to do the trick. It is enforcing as I'd like, just the error message is very cryptic when you put too much in. I'll play around with that a bit and see what I can do. I didn't think in that direction as I had hoped, that Typescript might have a syntax solution, but your solution is a very good second! Thanks. Feel free to write an answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: There is no way I think to do that with some syntax since typescript is using [structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) which is also known as duck-typing that only check for the required shape being reached. So you have another type, not Cat, but with the same structure and you won't get an error. I've added `symbol` thing to let the user know what exactly is wrong, instead of typing it as never

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript uses [structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system), also known as "duck-typing", which checks the shape of the type, compared to statically typed languages like Java, where the identity is checked. This means that you can expect type `X`, but be able to send type `Y` with the same shape and some extra properties.

Fortunately, there is a workaround. Not ideal, but at least it works.

Logic:
Since you want to check if the passed type is a member of a union(`Cat` or `CatWithOwner`), we will need to use [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to handle each member of union separately. After that, we will remove all keys of the member union from the checked type. If it is going to be an empty object after that, it means that there are no extra fields. However, it doesn't work recursively, thus if you would have nested extra fields, they would pass the check. Though, this type can be easily adapted. If the type isn't an empty object, we can return `never`, which will fire an error or a bit of complex error messaging to let the user know what is exactly wrong. The latter one can be done by adding some `symbol` property that will contain the names of the extra fields:

```
type ExactlyTheGivenType<T extends Base, Base> = Base extends Base
  ? {} extends Omit<T, keyof Base>
    ? T
    : Record<
        __internal__,
        `Following key is redundant: ${keyof Omit<T, keyof Base> & string}`
      >
  : never;
```

Usage:

```
const getNicknamedCat = <C extends Cat | CatWithOwner>(
  cat: ExactlyTheGivenType<C, Cat | CatWithOwner>,
): C extends CatWithOwner
  ? CatWithOwner & { nickname: string }
  : Cat & { nickname: string } => {
  return {} as any;
};
```

Testing:

```
getNicknamedCat({ name: 'Nick' });

getNicknamedCat({ name: 'Nick', owner: 'Winston' });

// expected error
// Argument of type '{ name: string; unrelated: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<symbol, "Following key is redundant: unrelated">'
getNicknamedCat({ name: 'Nick', unrelated: 'foo' });

getNicknamedCat({ name: 'Nick' });

getNicknamedCat({ name: 'Nick', owner: 'Winston' });

// expected error
// Argument of type '{ name: string; unrelated: string; unrelated2: string; }' 
// is not assignable to parameter of type
// 'Record<symbol, "Following key is redundant: unrelated" | "Following key is redundant: unrelated2">'
getNicknamedCat({ name: 'Nick', unrelated: 'foo', unrelated2: 'da' });
```

[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghsKBeKBvAsAKClAdnAWwgC4oBnYAJwEtcBzAbiwF8nMtRJYEB1a4ABYB5AO64IlZGiw4A9mImkKNem2ZQAZN2BsO4aAH0DtYBPwAbI1LIgCAI1nndmTtACiADzgBjYOZAAKgIQAOLUAG4QuAH6ADwBUBAeprgAJmRQAEJwZBAANFk5EAB8Utm5iclR6YW5MlAA-GjqSSk1QgT88QUA1hAgsgBmtSX1OE0BY1CkAEoQ3rKUqbFTODhGJmZwlgZ5q2sABgBijubytHRQfSBQ1BmUEKkArmlwuMCkACSo10NQHV0Ar1+n9yiVNOQqBdmAd9sV6qRxJFKM4FrgKFA6BBgAA5ajeHr4IipeCIFCxGCVNoZUlQAA+2j4glE4koxQAFPVvAhSJ4fH5AsEwpFonEYAVaQzSUzhAo2XtMABKUiU1rVGm8fiy1n1JrSrUsiQQ1B4fGEwgkSEqS7MBHaY2mglEy3KC5QdRIUoYbBQB7AJ6UXDNKA5EO4EBqZxY3Fm50khDsk3O0gAcjxBJT7sVUex6fNxNJibwFtTeZTBXkrNTfHRwFkuEzzGzWCwAHpW5VIL5HolKJRFlho3m44WkyWoGmzeWoC8HuYEI9U4NZLJG832Jgh7GLfHgEXkxOy1mczGnTvR8WiKWpxW5dXaBR62vnO3O-NTKle-3KG2OwBBSg6CeIh3igP5XAnMcrytC4GBnXA5wXVIlChVR4MQj8ACYUOtODmEzX9bgyXBZEQHIyGoOh8DscxoDrKAwDgSgLVMSRwP0QiUzmBYlliGx7EcAoACITnMM4RDda4iN9R4XlSN4PnQiB5w-IT6SgETTnOegrn6aSHmeV53lIWdlKQzChOKFNB1zbcCwTKDLUnDMClMlTFwnZdV1chCzKw1N5OfLAgA)

Comment: Re the duck typing: Why would that prevent TypeScript from checking against extra arguments? I mean, in many cases that is exactly what TypeScript does. E.g. this example:

`const f = (props: { a: string, b: number}) => {};
f({ a: "test", b: 3 , c: true});
`
Results in an error: (`Argument of type '{ a: string; b: number; c: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ a: string; b: number; }'.
///  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'c' does not exist in type '{ a: string; b: number; }'. [2345]`)

Comment: it can do that when you have the direct assignment, however, when you pass an argument to function this is not happening

Comment: Sorry, had send before the example was in. There you have a function parameter that rejects the extra argument.

Comment: But you are still doing the direct assignments. If you have a separate variable which you pass afterward you won't get the error. Like in [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAQwE4HMpwLxwN6IFxwBEMAprIQDRwBGBAzFSATEgK4lwC+okscAZpjgAKAA5IwoqAVwICsJAEsIKKrTgRWAW2okkXAJSYAfDi4BuAcORoDluEA)